# Hiding div with JavaScript based on data attribute of currently selected class

Tags: javascript

Given a class `season-list` with a data-attribute of `data-episode-count`, I have a script that will loop through all `season-list` classes and get the value of the `data-episode-count` value. However, it is currently returning only the value of the data attribute less than 6. I need to be able to hide the `js-show-more-trigger` class if the `season-list` class has fever than 6 in that `data-episode-count` value. Using `trigger.style.display = "none";` should be hiding the trigger class if the `data-episode-count` value is less than 6, but I'm getting the error `Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`

```js
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger');
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list")
for (let i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
  if (seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count') < 6) {
    trigger.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.season-list {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: block;">
  <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="3">
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099013"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099014"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099015"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="show-more"><span class="js-show-more-trigger">Show 
More</span></div>
```

**Codepen:** [LINK](https://codepen.io/testermytesty/pen/xWdgzX)

Comment: There's only one `.season-list` in your HTML. Do you want to hide the `trigger` when *any* `.season-list`s have fewer than 6 in their count, or when *every* has fewer than 6, or what? I guess your codepen isn't showing the whole HTML.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - The actual page can have anywhere from just one to many `season-list` classes. It should hide the trigger only when the `js-season-list-item` class has display set to block and data-episode-count is less than 6.

Comment: What's confusing is that every `.season-list` has its own `data-episode-count`. What happens when there are two `.season-lists`s and one has a count of 9 and the other has a count of 3?

Comment: So basically, this script is triggered when the user selects a season. It checks the currently visible `season-list` div is set to display block. If that div has a `data-episode-count` of 6 or less, the trigger should be hidden. Otherwise, it should be visible.

Comment: I think the best way to go about this, is to check which `season-list` has a style of display block. If it does, check the value of the `data-episode-count` attribute is less than 6. If it is, then set the trigger to display none. I'm trying to figure out how I can first check the display state of the `season-list` class and then use the data attribute to show or hide based on its value. Hopefully this clears up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `display` attribute to the array `trigger` not the elements it contains, that's why it's says `Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`.

You need to replace `trigger.style.display = "none";` with `trigger[i].style.display = "none";` to target each trigger separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
const trigger = document.querySelector('.js-show-more-trigger');
const seasonLists = document.querySelectorAll('.season-list');
seasonLists.forEach(seasonList => {
  if (Number(seasonList.getAttribute('data-episode-count') < 6)) trigger.style.display = "none";
});
```

Your initial `trigger` was an HTMLCollection, not an element - use querySelector when selecting a single element, and generally use NodeLists (qSA) when you want to iterate. The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Comment: this errors out with `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`